# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' on cycle for

Tags: typescript

this is part of my code:

```
for (const inputIdentifier in updatedControls) {
  formIsValid =
    ((updatedControls[inputIdentifier].valid || updatedControls[inputIdentifier].validation.required === false) && formIsValid) ||
    state.formIsValid;
}
```

the object that I use for the loop and that comes out from another using another function is

```
{profileImageId: {
    elementType: 'input',
    elementConfig: {
      type: 'file',
      placeholder: '',
      readOnly: true,
    },
    value: '',
    validation: {
      required: false,
    },
    valid: false,
    touched: false,
  },...}
```

but I got error:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ profileImageId: { elementType: string; elementConfig: { type: string; placeholder: string; readOnly: boolean; }; value: string; validation: { required: boolean; }; valid: boolean; touched: boolean; }; ... 4 more ...; color: { ...; }; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ profileImageId: { elementType: string; elementConfig: { type: string; placeholder: string; readOnly: boolean; }; value: string; validation: { required: boolean; }; valid: boolean; touched: boolean; }; ... 4 more ...; color: { ...; }; }'.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Showing what `updatedControls` contains would help in answering your question.

Comment: As it says in the error, TS is not sure it can index `updatedControls`, if you declare it as `const updatedControls:{[key in string]:any}={ profileImageId...` it should do the trick